# Merge Common Selectors (using Codekit)?

Tags: css, compression, sass, minify, codekit

If I have a file called 'structure.scss' and inside this file I have the code

```
body { margin: 20px; }
```

and I have another file called 'fonts.scss' with the following code inside

```
body { color: red; }
```

and I use codekit to compress I get the following code

```
body{margin:20px;}body{color:red;}
```

Is there any way to get the code minified even further or is there an option in codekit to do this to make the code...

```
body{margin:20px;color:red;}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there any tools for merging CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16762/are-there-any-tools-for-merging-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not possible in Codekit.