# How to combine all the css files various plugins in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, page-load-time

My website has 6 to 8 plugins installed and I am interested in knowing if there is a way to combine all css files from these plugins into one or two files

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This may help you [Combine and Minify Multiple CSS / JS Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9287823/combine-and-minify-multiple-css-js-files) or this [Are there any tools for merging CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16762/are-there-any-tools-for-merging-css)
By the way I found this : 
http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-minify/

> How Does it Work?
>
> WP Minify grabs JS/CSS files in your generated WordPress page and
>   passes that list to the Minify engine. The Minify engine then returns
>   a consolidated, minified, and compressed script or style for WP Minify
>   to reference in the WordPress header.

Comment: THe suggested plugin doesn't seem to work at all. Just tested.

Comment: The issue is that old plugins may not be using the proper way of including css/js. Looks like no merge/minify-plugin works without wp_enqueue. You might need to update these plugins, see here: http://4coder.info/en/blog/2010/how-to-properly-add-css-in-wordpress/