# How to merge and clean 2 css files with overlapping selectors/properties?

Tags: html, css

Here I am, trying to do a decent job at maintaining a site and adding new elements to it. But before that, I'd like to clean its css files.

That site is using 2 stylesheets, a v1 and a v2. Basically, the v2 adds new rules but also overrides rules/properties from the v1. So I can't just get rid of v1 because v2 doesn't contain all rules and properties.

Here's a quick example

From v1

```
.globalFooter {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

From v2

```
.globalFooter {
    font-size: 18px;
    display: inline;
}
```

And so, the result should be like

```
.globalFooter {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    display: inline;
}
```

I thought about manually merging v2 into v1, moving the new elements and overriding properties, but v2 is 3000 lines long...

So then I tried to find a tool that would do that automatically but I didn't find anything solid.
I need something that can merge the two files and consider that the 2nd file is loaded after, so it can overrides rules and properties of the 1st one.

Does someone know a good tool/script doing that ?

Thanks

Comment: Not really an answer to your question (which seems to have already been answered), but if you want to make maintenance easier in the future, consider using SCSS: http://sass-lang.com/.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is [This](http://zamez.org/factorcss)  and [This list](http://sixrevisions.com/css/css_code_optimization_formatting_validation/) of other helpful tools

Comment: Thank You much for CSS compressor. Not 100% ideally, had problems with media zones, but finally it really helped!

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for exactly the same thing as you do and couldn't believe that there is nothing easily to be found, even though the usecase seems to me pretty common.

Nevertheless, I found perfect tool which does exactly what you asked for - [CSSO](https://css.github.io/csso/csso.html). It merges same classes together and omits duplicate CSS rules.

Answer (score 2):

With this combination i solved and optimize the css to the maximum.

After configuring Grunt, install the following plugins:

- [grunt-postcss](https://github.com/nDmitry/grunt-postcss)
- [grunt-contrib-cssmin](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-cssmin)
- grunt-cssnano
- clean-css
- postcss-flexbugs-fixes
- autoprefixer

**Gruntfile.js**

Create the task to minify, merge selectors & properties, remove duplicates, etc.

```
cssmin: {
    options: {
        advanced: true, 
        mergeAdjacent: true,
        removeDuplicates: true,
        shorthandCompacting: false 
    },
    files: {    
        src: 'your/path/style.css',
        dest: 'your/path/style.min.css' 
    }  
},
```

After create a task to parse CSS, add prefixes and optimize more.

```
postcss: {
    options: {
        processors: [
            require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
            require('autoprefixer')({
                browsers: [  
                    'last 2 versions',  
                    'Edge >= 12',
                    'Explorer >= 9']
            }),
            require('cssnano')
        ],
        map: false,
    }, 
    files: {    
        src: 'your/path/style.min.css',
        dest: 'your/path/style.min.css' 
    }
}
```

Register a shortcut to the tasks

```
grunt.registerTask('css', ['cssmin', 'postcss']);
```

And Voilà!!

```
grunt css
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Merge the CSS stylesheets

```bash
cat a.css b.css d.css > merged.css
```

2. Create a NPM package in the current directory

```bash
npm init
```

3. Install grunt, postCSS and autoprefixer

```bash
npm install -g grunt
npm install grunt-postcss grunt-contrib-cssmin grunt-cssnano clean-css postcss-flexbugs-fixes autoprefixer
```

4. Create `Gruntfile.js` with the following config

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
      cssmin: {
         options: {
             advanced: true,
             mergeAdjacent: true,
             removeDuplicates: true,
             shorthandCompacting: false
         },
         files: {
             src: 'your/path/style.css',
             dest: 'your/path/style.min.css'
         }
      },
      postcss: {
         options: {
             processors: [
                 require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
                 require('autoprefixer')({
                     browsers: [
                         'last 2 versions',
                         'Edge >= 12',
                         'Explorer >= 9']
                 }),
                 require('cssnano')
             ],
             map: false,
         },
         files: {
             src: 'your/path/style.min.css',
             dest: 'your/path/style.min.css'
         }
      }
  });
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-postcss');
  grunt.registerTask('css', ['cssmin', 'postcss']);
};
```

5. Register a shortcut: `grunt.registerTask('css', ['cssmin', 'postcss']);`
6. Run `grunt css`

Answer (score -1):

You could use concat during build time to merge the two files

First you need to download it from npm.com/package/concat

then merge and require the new file

In node or package.json for automation, the merge would look something like this;

`concat ./v1.js ./v2.js -o /vOutput.js`