# Is there any tool to give me the merged version of two .css files?

Tags: css, git, merge

I have two `.css` files that I want to merge them. Something like what *git* dies. All I'm looking for is a tool like git which gets two files as input and generates a file as output which is the merged version of those two input files.

Is there such a thing?

---

#### For Example:

```
/* file1.css */
.header{
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 13px;
}


/* file2.css */
.header{
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
.footer{
    background-color: gray;
    position: reletive;
}


/* expected_result.css */
.header{
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 13px;
}
.footer{
    background-color: gray;
    position: reletive;
}
```

Comment: check out the link on factorCSS [merging css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16762/are-there-any-tools-for-merging-css) or [css optimize](http://www.cssportal.com/css-optimize/)

Comment: Are you merging changes introduced in different "branches", or are you applying one css on top of another and want the final result the way a browser would interpret it?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen The later.

Comment: Then that is not git merge